# How to take backup of crontab file of remote server from a script present in local server?

Tags: unix, cron

I want to take the backup of the crontab file of remote server. However I want to do it via a script which is present in local server.

I had included this command to take backup:
`crontab -l > $REMOTE_BACKUP_DIR/crontab_$RUN_DATE.bak`

But this is not working while run time and giving me the following error:

> You (user) are not allowed to use this program (crontab). See
>   crontab(1) for more information

I have done this by loggging in to the remote server using ssh and after some other operations, I am trying to backup the crontab file of that server.

Any suggestions where I am going wrong and how to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you tell us what user you are logging in as, what user you're running the script as and what user the crontab is owned by?

Comment: @rahoogan I  am looging in as user which is not root user e.g nameuser and with the same user I am trying running the script but the crontab is owned by root user and some other user but not me. I checked in /etc/cron.allow file and i am not included in that. I know that because of this I am not able to do that but just wondering if there is any other way to achieve this.

Comment: I have created a file with owner as user1 but when I am copying it to remote server from local server using rsync or scp the ownership is changed. How to avoid this? Tried many permutations but nothing is working till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user does not have access to run crontab (i.e absent in `/etc/cron.allow`), then you cannot run `crontab -l`. You will need to get someone who has privileged access to add you to this first. Additionally, if you wish to access another user's crontab you must have privileges to sudo as that user, or be a super user.

If the crontabs you wish to backup are owned by root, there is a chance that they are stored in the system crontab: `/etc/crontab` or any of the `/etc/cron*` files. If this is the case, you may have read-only access to those. So you can do:

```
cat /etc/crontab > $REMOTE_BACKUP_DIR/crontab_$RUN_DATE.bak
```